# Getter not working on object schema in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

This is my `Mongoose` schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongooseUniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');
const mongooseTimestamp = require('mongoose-timestamp');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const SectionSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: 'String', required: true},
    system: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'System'},
    subsystem: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'Subsystem'},
    createdBy: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'User'},
    allowedUsers: [{
        user: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId},
        actions: {type: 'String'},
        _id: false
    }],
}, {versionKey: 'versionKey'});

SectionSchema.plugin(mongooseTimestamp);
SectionSchema.plugin(mongooseUniqueValidator);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Section', SectionSchema);
```

the `actions` parameter save like this:

```
{"get":true,"post":true,"put":true,"delete":true}
```

I want to cast it to an object (in `Moongoose` find result), so I use `getter`:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongooseUniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');
const mongooseTimestamp = require('mongoose-timestamp');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const SectionSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: 'String', required: true},
    system: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'System'},
    subsystem: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'Subsystem'},
    createdBy: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'User'},
    allowedUsers: [{
        user: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId},
        actions: {type: 'String',get:toObject}, /* <------- */
        _id: false
    }],
}, {versionKey: 'versionKey'});

SectionSchema.plugin(mongooseTimestamp);
SectionSchema.plugin(mongooseUniqueValidator);

function toObject (v) { /* <------- */
    return JSON.parse(v);
}

SectionSchema.set('toObject', { getters: true }); /* <------- */
SectionSchema.set('toJSON', { getters: true }); /* <------- */

module.exports = mongoose.model('Section', SectionSchema);
```

But I don't know why **getter not working on object schema like `allowedUsers`.**

The find request:

```
this.model.Section.find(filterParameters, {
    _id: 0,
    versionKey: 0
}).skip(offset).limit(limit).sort({createdAt: sort})
    .populate('system', {_id: 0, name: 1})
    .populate('subsystem', {_id: 0, name: 1})
    .populate('createdBy', {_id: 0, username: 1})
    .populate({
        path: 'allowedUsers.user',
        model: "User",
        select: {username: 1, organization: 1, _id: 0},
        populate: {
            path: 'organization',
            model: 'Organization',
            select: {name: 1, _id: 0},
        }
    })
    .exec((error, sections) => {
        if (error) {
            reject({
                statusCode: "422",
                message: error
            });
        } else if ((!sections || sections.length === 0)) {
            reject({
                statusCode: "404",
                message: "No Result"
            });
        } else {
            resolve({
                data: sections,
                filterParameters: filterParameters
            });
        }
    });
```

Thanks for any idea...

Comment: Can you give your find request code ?